# How to read the values/secrets stored in Azure key vault

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a requirement to read the secrets/values from Azure key vault using clientId, clientSecret, TenantId, and vaultURL. I have values for all of these. I need to read the values stored on azure key vault using these values.

Any help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share these as well ( I see the one person answered ) just so you have them as well

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide

and

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45343 to grab the samples

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sample you could refer to this tutorial: [Azure Key Vault client library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net-v3). And below is my test code.

```
            string clientSecret = "client secret";
            string clientId = "client id";

            var secreturi = "https://****.vault.azure.net";

            KeyVaultClient kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
            {
                var adCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
                return (await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, adCredential)).AccessToken;
            });
            var keyvaultSecret = await kvClient.GetSecretAsync($"{secreturi}", "testsecret").ConfigureAwait(false);

            Console.Write(keyvaultSecret.Value);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps to read data from Azure key vault
[Link From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.secrets-readme)

Run 1 and 2 commands in windows Powershell

```
1. `az login` 
        Opens microsoft login page, enter your credentials and you should be logged in.

2. az ad sp create-for-rbac -n <somename> --skip-assignment 
        this outputs a JSON file 
        {
          "appId": "XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
          "displayName": "somename",
          "name": "XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX",
          "password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "tenant": "XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX"
        }
        
        use the above credentials to call Azure key vault service
        
        // Custom object 
        var request = new KeyVaultSecretRequest
        {
           ClientId = this._config["AzureKeyVault:ClientId"],
           ClientSecret = this._config["AzureKeyVault:ClientSecret"], //Password from above JSON
           EndPoint = this._config["AzureKeyVault:EndPoint"].ToUri(),
           TenantId = this._config["AzureKeyVault:TenantId"],
        };

        var options = new SecretClientOptions()
        {
           Retry =
           {
              Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
              MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
              MaxRetries = 5,
              Mode = RetryMode.Exponential,
           }
        };

        var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(request.TenantId, request.ClientId, request.ClientSecret);

        var client = new SecretClient(request.EndPoint, credentials, options);
        KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(request.Key).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.Item = secret.Value;
```